# Should I have an encapsulating ViewModel for each Model?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I've been working with WPF and MVVM a lot lately. I was under the impression that I understood the MVVM pattern quite well but I've begun having some doubts.

Right now, **I have an encapsulating ViewModel object for each Model object**. 
Let's say my Model contains two classes: `Property`, which contains a list of `PropertyValue`. In my ViewModel, I have a `PropertyVm`, which contains a `Property` and a list of `PropertyValueVm` (each containing a `PropertyValue`). Both Vm's implement a `BaseVm` which contains the `OnPropertyChanged` method.

Consider a View with two comboboxes, for `Property` and `PropertyValue`. The first combobox's `ItemsSource` will be bound to a collection of `PropertyVms` and the second combobox's `ItemsSource` will be bound to the `PropertyValueVms` of the `PropertyVm` selected in combobox 1.

This is all based on the article that got me to explore WPF and MVVM in the first place: [Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern, by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)

However, I'm becoming increasingly annoyed with the large amount of ViewModel classes my project contains, some of which contain very little code or simply nothing but the corresponding Model class.

Other implementations I've come across have the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the Model objects instead. This would mean you'd assign the Model objects to the Comboboxes directly. This would slim down the amount of ViewModel classes, but doesn't this violate the basics of MVVM?

I've also seen people advocating a single ViewModel per View. But I fear this would turn my ViewModel classes into humongous, incoherent walls of texts.

So my question in short: Should I have an encapsulating ViewModel for each Model? If not, then what is best practice?

Comment: I think you're over thinking this.  The practice of having a ViewModel for each View is what I would recommend.  I see no advantage in "Wrapping" model classes in a ViewModel. Have a ViewModel for each view that inherits from a baseviewmodel class that has all your propertychanged notification functionality.  Then have any required model classes for the view exposed as a public property which the view binds to.  The rest of the ViewModel will contain your business logic methods.

Comment: i would say you need a viewmodel for each view...

Comment: @StephenWilson my confusion comes in with the data model / dto type class that you may want to work with outside of the view itself. E.g. Your view might be associated with a ViewModel called PersonViewModel but to process data you may want to work with a PersonModel which can be serialized or stored in a DB. If the PersonModel properties are defined directly in the ViewModel, i.e. no seperate PersonModel, then you still have to somehow capture those values manually into another object to transfer it to a DB store?

Comment: @Jacques - Your `PersonModel` properties (Name, Age etc) would not be defined in the ViewModel, you would have a single property in the ViewModel of type `PersonModel` which will be databound to the UI.  If you really need two different types for the person property, I would suggest capturing data using one designed for that purpose and then using AutoMapper to map between the two.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary driver of MVVM is to maximise the testable code via the strong separation of presentation and presentation logic. Ideally we encapsulate the presentation logic in one or more view models - so in terms of your sub-question, have as many view models as makes sense. Dividing the functionality up into a series of smaller view models is good practice from my experience. But there is no one-size-fits-all way to implement this. So in some ways, the answer to the question is: it depends on your situation.

If your model never changes then you've reached a religious fork in the road. The pragmatist exposes the model to UI binding (guilty!!). The purist wraps the model in a view model because the VM sits between M and V in the design and if we don't dogmatically adhere to this then bad things must surely happen.

If your model changes then you have design choices. You can keep the model immutable and refresh your view model with a new version of the model and raise changes from there. Or, if your architecture facilitates an ever updating model that the UI just needs to represent then ask yourself if you truly gain by sticking a view model in the middle. But!! As soon as you get a sniff of logic creeping into the model then it's worth a view model.

Comment: what would be the reason to wrap a model into a view model? Especially if the model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` ? Wouldn't that be a unnecessary duplication?